# How do I send draft mail using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, imap, imapclient

How do I send a draft mail to draft folder using an API or via imap, SMTP?

```
mails.on("message", (message, seq) => {
    console.log('message',message);
    message.on("body", stream => {
        console.log("results123456--------",uid);
        let buffer = "";
        stream.on("data", chunk => (buffer += chunk.toString("utf8")));
        stream.once("end", () => mailBox.move(uid, "[Gmail]/Draft")); 
    });
});
```

Comment: There’s no specific API for this.  You download the Draft from IMAP using the normal fetch mechanisms, and then send it via SMTP using the normal SMTP mechanisms.

Comment: i tried but its not working. can you have code or references , how to do

Comment: _How_ does it not work?  What have you tried?  What is your debugging?  Were you able to download the message from IMAP in RFC822 format?  If so, start with that.

Comment: i tried in node js using nodemailer but its not working. actually question is how to stored the draft mail(create by myself through postman) in mail server through smtp

Comment: You do not use SMTP to store a Draft email.  You use IMAP's `APPEND` function to create a draft email.  You only use SMTP to send emails.  When you're ready to send the draft, you download the Draft using the `FETCH` command, modify the headers if necessary, then use SMTP to send it.  They are not generally integrated.